# codeigniter hook -post_controller. not logging query's used in model

Tags: php, codeigniter, hook

I am using hook(post_controller) to log execution time of the queries.

It is logging only queries used in controller but not logging which are used in Models.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "post_system" instead of "post_controller".